# fatal:Could not read from remote repository-github

Tags: github

I'm study use Github in ubuntu 14.04.

And now,I create a local repository and  want to create a repository on Github. However I can't solve this question.
I put all the contents of the local libraries pushed to the remote repository:

```
git remote add origin git@github.com:XXX/learngit.git
git push -u origin master
```

and error is:

```
Permission denied(publickey).
Fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are pushing via SSH so you need to  add a SSH key to  your github acc (see: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-ssh-keys/ ) or you could push via a other  protocol (see: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/ ).